# How to delete records from linked tables in vba

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I've no problems when deleting * records from local tables in my 2010 access db, but as I loop through my list and hit linked tables (local db, this is a fe/be setup) it fails with:
Run-time error '3131': Syntax error in FROM clause.  code:

```
    If sanityCheck2 = vbYes Then
        DoCmd.SetWarnings False
       'list the tables to purge here
        dalist = "tblLocal1 tblRemote-2 tblRemote-3"
        darray = Split(dalist, " ")
        For i = LBound(darray) To UBound(darray)
           DoCmd.OpenTable darray(i)
           DoCmd.RunSQL squirrel
        Next
        DoCmd.SetWarnings True
```

code works fine on tblLocal1, just not on any of the remotes.

I can open the table in datasheet and delete records no prob, just not through here.

Comment: Could you show the SQL command that is in "squirrel"?

Comment: If there is a syntax error in an SQL command then show us this SQL command! We cannot fix syntax errors if no syntax is visible.

Comment: When you are finished with the first item in your array (`tblLocal1`) are you 100% sure `tblRemote-2` is executing the same way you are thinking? Is that your real table name? And of course, we need to see the SQL.

Comment: @paulstock squirrel for the first table that throws the error is :
`DELETE * FROM tblRemote-2` pretty vanilla....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I bet this is choking on the SQL you build around table names with `-` inside them. SQL will see `DELETE * FROM tblRemote-2 WHERE ...` as `DELETE * FROM tblRemote - 2 WHERE ...` (non-sensical subtraction) unless you wrap your table names with square brackets.  Change that to `DELETE * FROM [tblRemote-2] WHERE ...` and you should be fine.

Comment: Applies to table names with spaces in them too!